# SQL Server: Return blank value when data not exists

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2017, not-exists

I'm facing an issue and i'm asking for your help. I have a table named as `freefieldassignment` that contains some data as seen below.

```
+-----------------+-------------------+--------+--------+
| Carrierobjectid | freefieldobjectid | value  |objectid|
+-----------------+-------------------+--------+--------+
|  90465009       | 75509             | D-AA   |90453004|
|  90465009       | 76378             | Yellow |90453062|
|  90465009       | 87395964          | ESCORT |90453072|
+-----------------+-------------------+--------+--------+
```

[image]

The last event with the value `ESCORT` sometimes may be deleted from the table, because of the users' selection from the application that he's using.

What i want to do is when `ESCORT` is deleted, return a blank value (or a null value)

I have tried to write a query using `NOT EXISTS`, but it's not working.

It goes like this

```
select carrierobjectid, 
case 
     when [freefieldassignment].[value] = 'Escort' then 'Escort'
     when NOT EXISTS (SELECT [freefieldassignment].[value] FROM [freefieldassignment]
     WHERE [freefielddefinition].[objectid]= 87409935
     AND [freefieldassignment].[carrierobjectid] = 90465009) then 'NULL'
```

Can anybody please give me some help? It will be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please include your data as a table in your question, not as a picture, since it makes it much easier for someone to play with your data in order to help you. Vert few people would consider retyping it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my test table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.freefieldassignment (
 Carrierobjectid NVARCHAR(255),
 freefieldobjectid NVARCHAR(255),
 value NVARCHAR(255),
 objectid NVARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO freefieldassignment (Carrierobjectid, freefieldobjectid, value, objectid)
VALUES
    ('1','2','N','2'),
    ('1','3','N','2'),
    ('1','3','N','3'),
    ('1','3','ESCORT','3')
```

Ans this i my query. Second query will generate row if no ESCORT row is found for values used in group by clause:

```
SELECT Carrierobjectid, freefieldobjectid, value, objectid  FROM freefieldassignment
WHERE Carrierobjectid = 1 AND objectid = 2  
UNION ALL
SELECT Carrierobjectid, null, null, objectid 
FROM freefieldassignment
WHERE Carrierobjectid = 1 AND objectid = 2  
GROUP BY Carrierobjectid, objectid  
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN value = 'ESCORT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Result:

```
Carrierobjectid | freefieldobjectid | value | objectid
1               | 2                 |   N   | 2
1               | 3                 |   N   | 2
1               | NULL              | NULL  | 2
```

When row ESCORT exist, second query from union doesn'y return data:

```
SELECT Carrierobjectid, freefieldobjectid, value, objectid  FROM freefieldassignment
WHERE Carrierobjectid = 1 AND objectid = 3
UNION ALL
SELECT Carrierobjectid, null, null, objectid 
FROM freefieldassignment
WHERE Carrierobjectid = 1 AND objectid = 3  
GROUP BY Carrierobjectid, objectid  
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN value = 'ESCORT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Result

```
Carrierobjectid | freefieldobjectid |   value  |    objectid
1               |   3               |   N      | 3
1               |   3               |   ESCORT | 3
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you want like below

```
 select carrierobjectid, 
case 
     when t.value = 'Escort' then t.value
     else null end as value
    FROM freefieldassignment  t
     WHERE t.objectid= 87409935
     AND t.carrierobjectid = 90465009
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not it. In this case it just shows me a blank table, with the columns' names only visible. I believe the use of NOT EXISTS should do the job.

Comment: @we_mor could you please add expected output